# vararg search: String with LIKE - android ROOM

Tags: android, android-room

How can we query room android with LIKE and vararg?

```
LIKE '%' || :search|| '%'
```

```
fun getSearch(vararg searchs: String): PagingSource<Int, Post>
```

Get database query with multiple search input string.

Answer (score 2):

It is not as simple as using a query that includes `LIKE '%' || :search|| '%'` as you need to handle each of the varargs independently.

Using `LIKE '%' || :search|| '%' will result in something (if there are 3 values specified) like:-

```
WHERE thecolumn LIKE '%'||?,?,?||'%'
```

That is each value has been specified as a comma separated bound value, a '?' (as if using `IN`).

The result being an SQLite Exception along the lines of `SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):` .

**Simple Way to achieve the objective**

A simple way could be to:-

**1)** Have an `@Query` function for a single search item e.g.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE thecolumn LIKE '%'||:singleSearchValue||'%'")
fun searchSingleValue(singleSearchValue: String): List<TheTable>
```

**2)** then have a function with a body that loops through the varargs that invokes the single query a number of times e.g.

```
@Transaction
@Query("")
fun searchV2(vararg search: String): List<TheTable> {
    val rv = mutableListOf<TheTable>()
    for (s in search) {
        rv.addAll(searchSingleValue(s))
    }
    return rv.toList()
}
```

- Note that the above code suits the working **DEMO**

**WORKING DEMO**

Consider the following (a simple @Entity annotated class, @Dao annotated interface and @Database annotated class that combines all):-

```
@Entity
data class TheTable(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val theColumn: String
)
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(theTable: TheTable): Long

    /* Used to demonstrate how the varargs are handled NOT TO BE USED */
    @Query("SELECT *,'%'||:search||'%' FROM thetable WHERE thecolumn LIKE '%'||:search||'%' OR id=1")
    fun searchV1(vararg search: String): List<TheTable>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE thecolumn LIKE '%'||:singleSearchValue||'%'")
    fun searchSingleValue(singleSearchValue: String): List<TheTable>

    @Transaction
    @Query("")
    fun searchV2(vararg search: String): List<TheTable> {
        val rv = mutableListOf<TheTable>()
        for (s in search) {
            rv.addAll(searchSingleValue(s))
        }
        return rv.toList()
    }
}
@Database(entities = [TheTable::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs
    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance= Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity of the demo */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

And to actually use the above and demonstrate the following activity code:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db= TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao=db.getAllDAOs()

        dao.insert(TheTable(theColumn = "Apple"))
        dao.insert(TheTable(theColumn = "Banana"))
        dao.insert(TheTable(theColumn = "Cherry"))
        dao.insert(TheTable(theColumn = "Damson"))

        for (tt in dao.searchV2("Apple","Orange","Tangerine","Damson")) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Found ${tt.theColumn} with ID of ${tt.id}")
        }
    }
}
```

**Result** (i.e. output to the log for the first run):-

```
D/DBINFO: Found Apple with ID of 1
D/DBINFO: Found Damson with ID of 4
```

i.e. **as expected the two rows have been found and nothing was found for the Orange and Tangerine searches.**

- Note the use of `@Transaction` and the empty `@Query` (the latter to fool Room into actually using a Transaction)
- Note that the above is not the most efficient way but does circumvent using  recursive common table expressions to process the comma separated list of values or instead building and using an `@RawQuery` to **OR** together multiple LIKE clauses (or alternately using the SQLite `instr` function).

The database itself, via App Inspection:-

[image]